# I wanted to know how to search 2 columns in the same mongodb table using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I wanted to know if it's possible for me to search 2 tables for example

**Guild and Guild2**

```js
 db.findOne(
        { Guild: message.guild.id, Guild2: message.guild.id },
        async (err, data) => {
            if (!data)
            return message.quote(lang.msg.msg);
            if (!data.Permanent && Date.now() > data.Expire) {
                data.delete();
                return message.quote(lang.msg.alert)
            }
```

Comment: Yes, you can search based on two fields of the same collection using [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)  .

Comment: @fractal397 how to do this? the way I did above is not working.

Comment: Can you explain more by updating the question, like with the response youre getting?And is ```Guild``` ObjectId?

Comment: @fractal397 When I put only `{ Guild: message.guild.id }` he returns perfectly but if i put `{ Guild: message.guild.id, Guild2: message.guild.id }` he doesn't return either of them

Comment: What do you mean either of them? They are two fields of the same document, so maybe theres no such document in collection. Also why do two fields have the same value?Also try putting double quotes on the field names.